# Buzzing and eventually loud cracking noises from the inside of the laptop (recording available), but the fans are checked and in excellent condition

Tags: laptop, fan, acer-aspire, noise

I hope I'm asking this in the right place, if not, feel free to brutally get rid of both me and my post, I'm just desperate at this point.

I own an Acer Aspire vn7-792g, I've had it for a few years. It's an excellent machine, but I've finally encountered a problem.

About three months ago, I started hearing a very quiet buzzing noise coming from the inside of the laptop, around the CD drive. Audio: https://old.vocaroo.com/i/s1GbCQkaMT8l

I assumed it's the fans, but since the temperatures seemed alright and the noise was very quiet, I ignored it. The buzzing appears after the laptop has been actively in use for some time, sometimes it's after 30 minutes of watching a video, sometimes after 3 hours of gaming, sometimes doesn't appear at all for a few days. What seems to be the thing that is making the noise appear the quickest and the most often, is watching a live-stream of any kind. However, disabling the most demanding app working at the moment (even if the CPU and GPU usage are at 2-6%) always immediately turned the noise off, as in instantly from 100% to 0%. However, once it appears the first time during the day, it's sure to return whenever going back to using any significant app for the rest of the day.

Unfortunately, after about a month, another noise appeared. Audio: https://vocaroo.com/jbrbWwraRfb (you can hear the original buzzing in the background, shows how much louder the cracking is).
And if you let it go for a while, it gets faster and faster until it's like this: https://vocaroo.com/7hDAFDCd17d

This noise appears only after the original buzz has been present for some time, and it happens much less frequently. While the original buzz occurs on 20-25 days of the month, the loud cracking noise appears about 5 times in a month. Interestingly, while the cracking and the buzzing seem to be slowly getting from 0 to 100, as in very slowly, they both immediately, instantly stop once an app is shut down.

I still assumed it's a damaged fan or something fan-related, and gave my laptop to a professional, who cleaned up the cooling and checked the fans. I only asked for this service and not diagnosis, because the clean-up and fan inspection takes several hours, while diagnosis at least 3 days.

Anyway, the cooling system was cleaned, the fans inspected. They showed me the photos. The cooling was somewhat dusty, so it was cleaned up, but the fans were both in excellent condition. So they assembled it again.

Unfortunately, the noises persist.

I've tried many things that I've found online:

- SSD and HDD scans are all green
- Drivers are up to date
- Power supply and battery are both original
- Noises happen on both battery and plugged in power supply
- I couldn't disable EIST, C1E, or Turboboost in my BIOS, but I used a Throttlestop program to do it, yet the noises are still here
- Tried different power settings and created a new one
- I've monitored the temperatures, and this doesn't really seem to be
  connected with the temperatures, there are times when the noises
  appear when the temperatures are at    lowest, other times the noises
  don't appear despite temperatures    being higher

Nothing seems to bring any result whatsoever. I notice no other issue with the laptop, everything seems to be working alright. I don't really mind the original, quiet buzz, but the cracking noise is too loud to ignore.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you all for your attention.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely the fan. You can see a tear down of your laptop here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQFn4n1Gf0M

The only thing even close to the disc drive is the smaller of the two fans... I'm sure that's what it is. You can hear similar noise on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u44iwZCKR08

at 1:24. As far as moving parts in a laptop goes, you don't have that many options. Its gotta be the fan.

As far as fixing it goes, you'll need to remove the fan and clean it, or maybe even replace it. My guess is the "professionals" you took it to just sprayed some canned air in it, but that wont fix anything if you have any sort of large debris in it, or the fan is off balance. I would take the fan out, and then unscrew the fan from its metal frame. If its out of balance, try to realign it or just get a new fan.

This guy takes apart the fan as I described above:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lxvmay2tn0

Comment: It sounds like the fan is not balanced and the blades are grazing its housing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I thought it's not the fans is because the guys at the shop actually disassembled the whole thing, I've seen the photos. But the sound on the video you provided is too similar to ignore so thank you.

Comment: Probably an alignment thing. They put it back together, but maybe not aligned well? Good luck.

Comment: Fun fact, it's not the fan after all. I gave my laptop to another shop, the guys tested the fans and determined that they aren't the problem after all. As of now they don't know what causes the noises, though they couldn't even replicate those at first, it's like it only happens to me :P The laptop is being diagnosed. They said that they'll be checking the speakers first, because that's the only thing they could come up with quickly, but it doesn't add up I think, I mostly use headphones, and both buzzing and crackling appear even when there's no audio. Nevertheless, the guys are testing it.